# Trigger Google Script function when new line is added

Tags: google-apps-script

On our website we are using to form to collect data and then using Zapier to put the data into a Google Sheet.  After the data is imported, in the last few columns I need to add some functions to do some math, concat text, etc.

I wrote a google script to "fillDown" the data.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRangeImgName = ss.getRange(2,15, lr-1);
  var fillDownRangeQty = ss.getRange(2,16, lr-1);

  ss.getRange("O2").setFormula('=CONCATENATE(M2,"_",N2,"_",F2,"_",G2,".jpg")');
  ss.getRange("P2").setFormula('=CONCATENATE("TM-",E2)');

  ss.getRange("O2").copyTo(fillDownRangeImgName);
  ss.getRange("P2").copyTo(fillDownRangeQty);
}
```

My question is, after Zapier inserts the data into the sheet, what is the best way to trigger my function to add the formulas?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the prepared event triggers are fired only when the spreadsheet is manually edit. So for example, how about the following workarounds? When the value is put to Spreadsheet, 1. Run the process you want at Zapier side. 2. Run the script by requesting to Web Apps from Zapier. 3. Check updating Spreadsheet using the time-driven trigger. If these were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I ended up just adding a button on the sheet that manually runs the function.  Simple enough.  Guess there wasn't much of a need to make sure it was fully automated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: It is possible for a script to run when a new row is inserted. Out of interest, does Zapier insert a new row or just paste new values to your spreadsheet on the next empty row?

Comment: If you use a Google Form you could try using the [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger